# PHP and MySQL defining variable tables or columns with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I always use PDO when making MySQL connections from PHP and it works as expected when my execution variables are parts of the `WHERE` statements in the query. An example of this could be this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(['id' => 1]);
```

Let's say I want to fetch a dynamic column name in the query above. I would expect the following query to work:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, :dynamic_column FROM users WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(['dynamic_column' => 'age', 'id' => 1]);
```

...but it doesn't. The only way I can add dynamic column names or table names to a query is by adding php-variables directly to the query like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, $dynamic_column FROM users WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(['id' => 1]);
```

... which will work. But by going with this solution, the whole point of PDO is gone.

My question is now; what is the best practice when the variable I want to add to my query is a table name or a column name?

Comment: I'm not sure about best practice, but I would recommend creating arrays of acceptable values, and check the input against that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter has some options

Comment: To elaborate on what aynber said, make a list of allowed values and check against that first. Then concatenate the field or table name into the query. You cannot use prepared statements to sanitize them.